# Angular route link not updating the page (url doesn't change either)

Tags: angular

I've got an angular 8 site. I've got a component where I'd like to update the UI after toggling some item from my database. In essence, I've got active projects and inactive projects. I've placed a button on the page to call the API and change the active status from true to false or vice versa, but then back in the angular component, I'd like to update the UI without a full page refresh. I'm using a page refresh function to make it look seamless to the user. Currently, the page updates correctly which is great but then I'm not able to routerLink to any other pages using my menubar. Any help would be appreciated.

```
toggleStatus(id, status) {
    let changeStatus = {
      active: status
    }
    this._projectService.toggleStatus(id, changeStatus).subscribe(
      response => {
        console.log(response['message']);
      this.reloadComponent();
      },
    error => console.log(error['message'])
    )
  }


///// FUNCTION TO RELOAD PAGE AFTER DELETE /////
  reloadComponent() {
    this._router.routeReuseStrategy.shouldReuseRoute = () => false;
    this._router.onSameUrlNavigation = 'reload';
    this._router.navigate(['admin/projects']);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change `this._router.navigate(['admin/projects']);`  to

```
 this._router.navigate(['./admin/projects']);
```

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately, this doesn't work - the same result. Either ./ or / yields the same thing, a locked router. I'm trying to click off this page to another page and it's not responding until I fully refresh the browser window.

Answer (score 0):

A couple years later hahaha but I ran into the same issue. I am really bad at explaining so I'll use an example and docs [link](https://angular.io/api/router/ActivatedRoute#snapshot) to explain. Basically you will need to `ActivatedRoute` api for this.

Example:
In my app-routing.module.ts I have this route below defined.

```
{
    path: ':path/product/:id',
    loadComponent: () => import('./product/product.component').then(m => m.ProductComponent)
  }
```

In other to react to the dynamic variables passed in the route, you define a function below. Hope it helps!

```
import {ActivatedRoute, Params} from "@angular/router";

private readonly route = inject(ActivatedRoute);
this.route.params
    .pipe(
      switchMap((param: Params) => {
        const obj = param as { path: string, id: string }
        
        // further implementation
      })
    );
```